# NextJS on Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, next.js, deployment, next-auth

After build my NextJs application and run, it works well on apache using the follow *.htaccess*. However I'm having problem with dynamic routes (something like: **posts/[id]**), for these cases it is returning chunk erros.

```js
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4001/ [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4001/$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you use mod_rewrite for this you should still include a ProxyPassReverse directive.

from the Apache docs:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://old.example.com/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://old.example.com/"
```

> Discussion: In each case, we add a ProxyPassReverse directive to
> ensure that any redirects issued by the backend are correctly passed
> on to the client.
>
> Consider using either ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch whenever possible in
> preference to mod_rewrite.